# Parse Android Not able to add new users from the app without logInInBackground

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to use the current user to add new users in parse, using logInInBackground seems to make the added user to be the user to be loggedin in the current session

I tried:

```
ParseObject member = new ParseObject("User");
        member.put("username",uname);
        member.put("email",email);
        member.put("password", password);

        member.put("FirstName", fname);
        member.put("LastName", lname);
        member.put("isAdmin", isAdmin);
        member.put("isActive", isActive);

        member.saveInBackground();
```

and this

```
ParseUser member = new ParseUser();
        member.setUsername(uname);
        member.setEmail(email);
        member.setPassword(password);

        member.put("FirstName",fname);
        member.put("LastName", lname);
        member.put("isAdmin", isAdmin);
        member.put("isActive", isActive);

        member.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/create-a-new-user-without-changing-the-current-one) you can't create a new user directly without changing the current user.

The solution is to write a cloud function that creates the new user.

Comment: I will look it up, Thanks